# Get an Image using button onClick

Tags: android, android-image, bitmapimage

I'm trying to **get an Image and want to put it into `HashMap`** using `Button.onClickListener()

I am sure i am doing mistake here:

```
   String s_image = imgv.toString();
```

I guess here i should use ImageView in place of String, but having doubt how and what code need to write

**Logcat Says:**

```
    05-11 10:56:51.760: D/dalvikvm(299): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2253 objects / 144464 bytes in 48ms
05-11 10:57:16.500: D/Single(299): ImageURL :: http://2.imimg.com/data2/EE/RJ/MY-932393/children-suits-250x250.jpg
05-11 10:57:17.920: D/Single(299): Title :: Kids
05-11 10:57:17.920: D/Single(299): Image :: android.widget.ImageView@46092008
```

Single.java Code:

```
public class Single extends Activity {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "Single";

public static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
public static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

String s_title, s_image; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information_product);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TITLE);        
    String image = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGE);
    Log.d(Single.LOG_TAG, "ImageURL :: " + image);


    final ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    final ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_thumb);
    final TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);

    txttitle.setText(title);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, imgv);

    Button mImgAddCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    mImgAddCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            s_title = txttitle.getText().toString();
            Log.d(Single.LOG_TAG, "Title :: " + s_title);
            s_image = imgv.toString();
            Log.d(Single.LOG_TAG, "Image :: " + s_image);

            if (Session.item_data.size() <= 0) {
                HashMap<String, String> h_obj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                h_obj.put(TAG_TITLE, s_title);
                h_obj.put(TAG_IMAGE, s_image);
                Session.item_data.add(h_obj);                       
            }           
        }
    });
```

Comment: use activity context in place of getApplicationContext(). Show us image loader class

Comment: Check `image` link is correct or not

Comment: Check the image link. check the string image  String image = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGE);

Comment: u r getting a **MalformedURLException**..docs.oracle says **Thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed.**..check with ur URL and Protocol that u r using..

Comment: check if you have added internet permission in manifest file

Comment: @ChulbulPandey added internet permission manifest??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MalformedURLException.html. Either your url is not correct ie broken or your have not mentioned internet permission in manifest

Comment: String s_image = imgv.toString(); why are you doing this. whats printed is logcat is corect

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i am sure i am doing mistake here actually i want to get an image but i guess i should use ImageView in place of String but confuse how can i use this and log says: Image :: android.widget.ImageView@46092008

Comment: what your doing ins converting imageview object to string. You are not doing anything with your image actualy

Comment: @Raghunandan yes buddy and that's why i need your help

Comment: @ChulbulPandey A HashMap would get destroyed when your application is destroyed & restarted. i suggest you store images in sdcard and then get the image when needed or use application specific cache directory to store and retrieve http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29

Comment: @Raghunandan buddy i am using cache and storing it into sdcard, see these lines: if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ShoppingCart/Images");    and i don't want to store any information in Database making for a Session only

Comment: @ChulbulPandey buddy check this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Button mImgAddCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add); 
mImgAddCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

public void onClick(View v) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

s_title = txttitle.getText().toString(); 
Log.d(Single.LOG_TAG, "Title :: " + s_title);   
image = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGE); 
if (Session.item_data.size() <= 0) { 
HashMap<String, String> h_obj = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
h_obj.put(TAG_TITLE, s_title); 
h_obj.put(TAG_IMAGE, image); 
Session.item_data.add(h_obj);   
}   
} 
});
```